# Expanders in distinct columns in one row. Expand to the full row

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two expanders in one grid row but in distinct columns. How can I expand each of it to the full row but not on column only.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="40" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Controls:Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="expander2" Header="Header1" 
                           MinHeight="33" Padding="3">
        <TextBlock Text="SomeText1" />
    </Controls:Expander>

    <Controls:Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="expander1" Header="Header2" 
                           MinHeight="33" Padding="3">
        <TextBlock Text="SomeText2" />
    </Controls:Expander>
</Grid>
```

expander1 and expander2 should expand to the whole row 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce the triggers for Expanders that check their `IsExpanded` property and set their `Grid.RowSpan` as 2.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**For silverlight**

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
     <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan"
             Value="{Binding IsExpanded,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                               Self},
                             Converter={StaticResource
                                local:ExpansionToRowSpanConverter}}"
   </Style>
```

Code behind ... (this is just for illustration)

```
      ExpansionToRowSpanConverter.Convert(....)
      {
          return (bool)value ? 2 : 1;
      }
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work fine. Could you give any advices solving this problem in Silverlight where triggers are not supported?